# How to make two separate mac terminals (command prompt windows) send text messages to each other without getting the "Address already in use" error?

Tags: java, eclipse, cmd

I'm trying to create a text messaging program in java which will use two separate mac terminals (command prompt windows) to send and receive text messages to each other (UTF-8 strings) using two separate .java files in Eclipse (one is the server one is the client) (the two .java files have  separate threads, one is called Server, the other is called Client)

The left window will be the client and the right window will be the server

The command line arguments for the server will be:

```
java DirectMessengerServer -l 3000
```

The command line arguments for the client will be:

```
java DirectMessengerClient 3000
```

The "-l" will be used later to differentiate between client and server later (ignore this for now)

The port number will be 3000.

Screenshot of error: 
[image]

Code of client (DirectMessengerClient.java):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class DirectMessengerClient
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        Thread Client = new Thread () 
        {
              public void run ()
              {   
                    System.out.println("Client thread is now running");
                    ServerSocket server_socket = null;
                    Socket client_socket;
                    Socket smtpSocket = null;  
                    DataOutputStream outputstream = null;
                    DataInputStream inputstream = null;

                            try
                            {
                                System.out.println("Try block begins..");
                                int port_number1= Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
                                ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port_number1);
                                System.out.println("Listening for connections..");
                                System.out.println( "Listening on port: " + Integer.toString( port_number1 ) );
                                Socket socket = listener.accept();
                                client_socket= server_socket.accept();
                                BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client_socket.getInputStream(), "UTF8"));
                                PrintWriter output= new PrintWriter( client_socket.getOutputStream(), true );
                                outputstream = new DataOutputStream(smtpSocket.getOutputStream());
                                inputstream = new DataInputStream(smtpSocket.getInputStream());
                                String input_line= reader.readLine();
                                System.out.println( "Received from client: " );
                                System.out.println( input_line );
                                output.println( input_line );
                            }
                            catch ( Exception e )
                            {
                                System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
                            }
                            //server.close();
                       // }
                    }

        };
        Client.start();
    }
}
```

Code of Server (DirectMessengerServer.java):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class DirectMessengerServer
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        Thread Server = new Thread () 
        {
              public void run ()
              {   
                    System.out.println("Server thread is now running");
                    ServerSocket server_socket = null;
                    Socket client_socket;
                    String message1;

                    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
                    {
                        if(args[i].equals("-l"))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                System.out.println("Try block begins..");
                                int port_number1= Integer.valueOf(args[i+1]);
                                ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port_number1);
                                System.out.println("Listening for connections..");
                                System.out.println( "Listening on port: " + Integer.toString( port_number1 ) );
                                Socket socket = listener.accept();
                                client_socket= server_socket.accept();
                                BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client_socket.getInputStream(), "UTF8"));
                                PrintWriter output= new PrintWriter( client_socket.getOutputStream(), true );
                                String input_line= reader.readLine();
                                System.out.println( "Received from client: " );
                                System.out.println( input_line );
                                output.println( input_line );
                            }
                            catch ( Exception e )
                            {
                                System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
                            }
                            //server.close();
                        }
                    }
              }
        };
        Server.start();
    }
}
```

My question is: Is there a way to remove the "Address already in use" while having the same port number or perhaps I should use inetaddress or something instead? I am not sure how to make these two programs communicate (communication being to have text messages being outputted from one to the other, like text messaging between two phones), but that is the goal I would like to know how to accomplish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is: you start the server and the port is getting occupy by the server just waiting for the client to come, then you start the client which is somehow (maybe a copy paste issue) creating a server too.. then the connection fails because the port is already used by your previously server...

remove the server part from  **DirectMessengerClient** class

Comment: Which lines in particular are the server part of server part of the directmessengerclient? are you talking about the lines inside the try block?

Comment: `ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port_number1);`  Appears to try to open a server socket and listen on the same port the server is using.